# AndroidX AAPT colors not found

Tags: androidx, aapt

I checked a couple of tutorials and then dove in to Refactor>Migrate to AndroidX. I imported ActivityCompat, ContextCompat and DrawableCompat.
But now I am stuck getting a compile completed because of this error:
AAPT: C:\Program Data\Android\QiewProjects\DBQiew\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v31\values-v31.xml:3: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found.
C:\Program Data\Android\QiewProjects\DBQiew\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v31\values-v31.xml:4: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_900 not found.
C:\Program Data\Android\QiewProjects\DBQiew\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v31\values-v31.xml:5: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_0 not found.
.
.
.

It continues on for about 21 missing items. It appears AndroidX is looking for color files that are missing.
I have spent hours looking for a similar posting, but there aren't any. I have even tried Invalidate caches/Restart but that changed nothing.

Please point me to an explanation to find the missing files or disable the hunt for them. BTW I am using Studio 4.1.2 and compile and target SDK versions 29.

Comment: Also tried Clean Project.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I had to revise the compile and targetSDK versions from 29 to 31.
It was not mandatory, but I also upgraded the following versions in app/build.gradle:

```
androidx.appcompat.appcompat:1.0.0 -> 1.4.1
androidx.core.core:1.0.0 -> 1.7.0
androidx.constraintlayout.constraintlayout:1.1.2 -> 2.1.3
```